# Visual Studio Code React Native suddenly won’t debug. "Error: Error while executing command (error code 101)"

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code

Seemingly out of absolutely nowhere and for no apparent reason I’m getting this error in the Visual Studio Code output when trying to debug run iOS:

> Error: Error while executing command
> '/Users/blaa/node_modules/.bin/react-native run-ios --scheme Play-Dev
> --no-packager --verbose': Error while executing command '/Users/blaa/blaa/node_modules/.bin/react-native run-ios --scheme
> Play-Dev --no-packager --verbose' (error code 101)

This worked fine yesterday. It’s working if I switch to my develop branch, just not when I’m on my feature branch. Another developer can currently successfully VSC debug both branches.

Things I’ve tried:

- Nuked yarnopods 10-20X
- Nuked all yarnopod lock files  1X
- Deleted Derived Data 2X
- Mac Restart
- VSC Restart 5-10X
- Switch the VSC terminal to bash not zsh
- Nuked sim 3X
- $ yarn cache clean
- $ echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=582222 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p   - that old chestnut
- Apologized to the old Gods and the new for anything bad I ever said about Xcode
- Branch switch back to develop - nuked yarnopods - VSC debugging IS working
- Branch switch back to feature branch - nuked yarnopods - VSC debugging NOT WORKING with mystery error 0

Debugging using Xcode and React Native Debugger is working, although breakpoints stopped working a few months ago in RNDB, so that’s pretty much useless.

Answer (score 0):

FIXED. Deleted the entire local repo. Cloned fresh from origin. Added the launch.json file again.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting similar errors and found this fix:

1. If there are Flutter (and Dart) extensions in Visual Studio Code uninstall them.
2. Close Visual Studio Code, delete the `.vscode` folder and open Visual Studio Code again.
3. Configure the "Run and debug" panel again so you can run the app.